# Replacing strings in an array in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int i = 0;
   char c;
   char *array;
   char *data;
   char *ret;


   array = (char *) malloc(100);
   data = (char *) malloc(strlen(argv[1])+1);
   strcpy(data, argv[1]);    // store the word john into the array called data
   while((c=getchar())!=EOF) // stores the words in the txt file into array
   {
        array[i]=c;
        i++;
   }
    ret = strstr(array, data); // find a substring (john in this case)
    printf("The substring is: %s\n", ret);
    *ret = "jack"; // Doesn't work here, but I want to replace john with jack
    free(data);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

I've done some research on the strstr tool and it seems that it finds the first occurance of a substring and returns a pointer to that position. Using that pointer I want to modify it, but it's not going so well for me.

My terminal at Ubuntu looks like this when I run it:

./a.out john < beatles.txt

My beatles text looks like this;

paul

john

ringo

john

In the end I want my array which contains those 4 names to have john replaced with jack for example. Is there anyway I can do this using the pointer given to me by the strstr tool?

I think I will need a while llop or for loop tog et every john in the array to be repalced with jack*

Comment: Long before the search becomes a problem, you're going to overrun the array (that file is certainly longer than 14 characters).

Comment: Right, I changed it to 100, I kind've overlooked that since this won't even compile because of the *ret = "jack" line.

Comment: Instead of `*ret="jack";` do `memcpy(array, "jack", strlen("jack"));`. In any case, you have to be careful with what string you are replacing the contents of the array with. This will also overwrite other parts the array if the length of the string you replace with is different. If you want replace *all* instances (of `"john"` with `"jack"` for example), use a loop over `strstr()`.

Comment: Is this a homework or something? I think C is nearly the worst choice of a language for this kind of task.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to modify the pointer, you want to modify what the pointer points to. Also the `ret` points to a character, so `*ret` is the first character of a sequence of characters, in this case the character 
`'j'`, so you can't just assign a string to it. You must replace each character of that sequence. The function `memcpy` can help you with that.

To replace the other occurrences of "john" you can use this loop:

```
while(ret = strstr(array, data)){
    printf("The substring is: %s\n", ret);
    memcpy(ret, "jack", strlen("jack"));
}
```

`strstr()` returns `NULL` if it does not find anything, and when that happens you are going to break out of the loop.

There are some problems with your code too:

- You can use `argv[1]` in place of `data`.
- It is better to copy a file to a buffer with calls to `fread()`.